# VS 2010 the property 'Click' does not exist in type...?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, events, click

As you may have guessed I'm a noob. I noticed that, when trying to make a windows phone app with VS express for windows phone, I can quickly run into problem if I:

- Add a text block in xaml
- Add  Click="thing" in the markup for the textblock
- Declare `private void thing(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      { return; }`  in the code behind

VS doesn't let me compile because
The property 'Click' does not exist in type 'TextBlock' in the xml namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

I know this forum is normally not for such basic things, but I really don't understand how can I mess it up by just adding these two things.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "Click" isn't an event that TextBlock has. What are you trying to do, perhaps we can suggest an alternative control.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, you could have easily found that one out yourself by checking [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate is here, Use "mouseLeftButtonDown" event, this event will work same as clicked event and also available for almost all basic controls

Comment: Yes, that's what I did eventually. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, there's no click in TextBlock in Silverlight... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(v=vs.95).aspx

GotFocus may be the event you're looking for... Or you may want a different element type altogether.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the kind help and the links. I'm actually trying to learn as fast as I can and begin to mix things up. I thought I had previously succeded at putting a Click property anywhere I wanted but in fact I had used an avent handler in my code-behind. Thanks again